# why we use images in CI CD pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, cicd

actually i'm facing a problem in this code :
Sorted

```
  - Changes
  - Lint
  - Build
  - Tests
  - E2E
  - SAST
  - DAST
  - Publish
  - Deployment

#  Get Runner Image
image: Node:latest

#  Set Variables for mysql
**variables:**
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 
   ..
   ..

 **script:**
    - ./addons/scripts/ci/lintphp.sh
```

why we use image I asked some one said that we build on it like the docker file command FROM ubuntu:latest
and one other told me it's because it executes the code and I don't actually know the script tag above what evem does it mean to execute inside the image or on the runner?

Answer (score 2):

[GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) is an open source application that collects pipeline job payload and executes it. Therefore, it implements a number of [executors](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) that can be used to run your builds in different scenarios, if you are using a docker executor you need to specify what image you will be using to run your builds.